# Can't CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm trying to create an external data source to access Azure Blob Storage. However, I'm having issues with creating the actual data source.

I've followed the instructions located here:
[Examples of bulk access to data in azure blob storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage) and 
[Create external data source - transact sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql). I'm using SQL Server 2016 on a VM accessing via SSMS on a client machine using Windows Authentication with no issues. Instructions say creating this external data source works for SQL Server 2016 and Azure Blob Storage.

I have created the Master Key:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = <password>
```

and, the database scoped credential

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadCountries  
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = <key>;
```

I have verified both of these exist in the database by querying sys.symmetric_keys and sys.database_scoped_credentials.

However, when I try executing the following code it says 'Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobCountries
WITH  (
    TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
    LOCATION = 'https://<somewhere>.table.core.windows.net/<somewhere>', 
    CREDENTIAL = UploadCountries  
);
```

Your thoughts and help are appreciated!

Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In “[Examples of Bulk Access to Data in Azure Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql#arguments)”, we can find:

> Bulk access to Azure blob storage from SQL Server, requires at least SQL Server 2017 CTP 1.1.

And in **Arguments** section of “[CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-data-source-transact-sql)”, we can find similar information:

> Use BLOB_STORAGE when performing bulk operations using BULK INSERT or OPENROWSET with SQL Server 2017

You are using SQL Server 2016, so you get `Incorrect syntax near 'EXTERNAL'` error when you create external data source for Azure Blob storage.

Comment: Well, it’s wonderfully helpful that it says it applies to SQL Server 2016 but I suppose there can always be caveats. Thank you for noting those. I obviously glossed over them trusting too heavily on the opening statement.

Comment: How do you even set up an azure sql database where you can select the version to be 2017? I've created a couple databases on Azure, but don't see the ability anywhere to change this. When I run `SELECT @@VERSION` they all return v12, but 2017 is v13.