# How to retrieve version history information and run history of a azure logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm kind of new developing in Azure, I developed a **logic app** that works correctly and I need to import to an **azure sql datawarehouse** the version history and the run history of this logic app. I created an Analytics logs workspace and I activated the logs, the logs are correctly stored in a blobstorage.

I need to extract the run/version history of this logic app to feed a datawarehouse table but I'm facing two problems:

1. **For the run history:** How can I retrieve the information stored in a blobstorage? I tried to create an external table in my datawarehouse (like described here 
   [Can't CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739126/cant-create-external-data-source-in-sql)) but I get the following error when I tried to create the external source:

   > CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE BlobStorageDataSource WITH  (
   >            TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
   >            LOCATION = 'https://primarystoragedwh.table.core.windows.net/blobstoragedwh', 
   >            CREDENTIAL = AzureBlobStorageCredential );
   >
   > Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
   >   Parse error at line: 4, column: 12: Incorrect syntax near 'BLOB_STORAGE'.
2. **For the version history:** Im trying to use a scrip task in SSIS to import the rest api data from (as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/logic/workflowversions/list) but I dont know how to code to retrieve the data from the rest call.

Your thoughts and help are appreciated!
Manuel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your first question, there are two possible issues in your operation.

1. As the answer of [your refered SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739126/cant-create-external-data-source-in-sql) said, the issue might be caused by the incompatible version of SQL Server. Please check the SQL Server version you used and make sure that be `SQL Server 2017 (14.x)`.
2. The host `*.table.core.windows.net` is for Table Storage, not Blob Storage which be `*.blob.core.windows.net`.

To answer your second question, an access token passed for the REST API is required. So you have to follow the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/) to know the flow of calling a REST API with access token. I don't know what programming language you used, but you can try to refer to my answer for a similar needs [How to check the health of application gateway in Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367621/how-to-check-the-health-of-application-gateway-in-azure/42416200#42416200) or other offical code samples as below.

1. [Mange Azure Virtual Machines using REST API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/virtual-machines-dotnet-rest-api-manage/) in C#
2. [Microsoft Azure Billing API Code Samples: RateCard API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/billing-dotnet-ratecard-api/) in C#
3. [Microsoft Azure Billing API Code Samples: RateCard API](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/billing-python-ratecard-api/) in Python